# Searching for a specific character set in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a set of characters with some missing values like this

```
bp <- rep(NA, 5)
bp[c(2,4)] <- c("sugar","milk")
bp

> bp
[1] NA  "sugar" NA  "milk" NA
```

I'm looking for a way to use ***bp*** for searching a larger data frame in order to find similar occurances of ***bp*** (and where), but with NAs filled.

For example,

```
[1] any1  "sugar" any2  "milk" any3 
[2] any2  "sugar" any5  "milk" any1 
[3] any6  "sugar" any1  "milk" any3 
[4] any8  "sugar" any7  "milk" any6
[5] any1  "sugar" any2  "milk" any3
```

**EDIT:** A part of the data frame looks something like this

```
c("milk", "sugar", "sugar", "creme", "carw", "milk", "creme", "carw", 
"sugar", "carw", "creme", "sugar", "sugar", "milk", "milk", "creme", 
"sugar", "sugar", "carw", "carw", "carw", "milk", "sugar", "sugar", 
"carw", "sugar", "milk", "sugar", "creme", "carw", "carw", "carw", 
"creme", "carw", "carw", "creme", "creme", "milk", "carw", "milk", 
"milk", "creme", "creme", "creme", "milk", "milk", "creme", "carw", 
"carw", "milk", "milk", "creme", "creme", "carw", "carw", "milk", 
"sugar", "carw", "milk", "carw", "creme", "sugar", "sugar", "creme", 
"sugar", "sugar", "creme", "sugar", "carw", "sugar", "carw", 
"carw", "creme", "sugar", "milk", "milk", "carw", "carw", "milk", 
"creme", "sugar", "carw", "milk", "sugar", "sugar", "milk", "sugar", 
"creme", "milk", "milk", "carw", "milk", "sugar", "carw", "sugar", 
"carw", "creme", "creme", "carw", "milk", "milk", "milk", "milk", 
"carw", "carw", "milk", "milk", "carw", "sugar", "milk", "milk", 
"milk", "creme", "carw", "creme", "milk", "milk", "milk", "creme", 
"carw", "milk", "carw", "carw", "carw", "carw", "carw", "carw"
)
```

I would normaly use this for searching the entire data frame, but in this situation it's tricky.

```
library(data.table)

n1 <- length(bp)
bp.pos <- setDT(data.frame)[,  which(Reduce(`&`, Map(`==`, shift(value1, seq(n1)-1, 
                                                                             type = "lead"), 
                                                                 bp)))]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your data example in valid R syntax - `dput()` can help create copy/pasteable resuts. Right now I can't tell if it's a data frame with one column, 5 columns, or something else. Also please show your desired output.

Comment: I'm still confused by the `any*` numbers. Do they matter? Why does the second line start with `any2` instead of `any1`? Also, your text says "find similar occurrences ... and where", but your desired output doesn't seem to indicate the "where" at all. Which do you want?

Comment: @Gregor by `any` I mean any instance form the dataframe. It could be any of the unique values in any arrangement. I use the code at the bottom to find the "where" but I can't make it work with the NAs from the `bp` set

Comment: I don't understand if you need to distinguish between `any1` and `any2` and all of the other `any*`. Would you be happy with an answer that had `NA` for all of your `any*` values? Or would you prefer the actual values? Or do you need the `any*` placeholders (in which case please explain the logic behind the numbers).

Comment: And I can't make the code at the bottom work with the data you shared. I defined `data.frame = data.frame(value1 = <the character vector you shared>)`, and I get `integer(0)` as the result for `bp.pos`. This also makes it hard to understand your goal.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for your time on this. Your answer was on point and helped me find a way to get thought my issue. I assume that the code at the bottom returns `integer(0)` because of the NAs in `bp`; maybe that is why I could not make it work either? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt based I what I understand of your problem. I call the vector you shared `x`:

```
test = sapply(seq_along(bp), function(i) bp[i] == x[(0 + i):(length(x) - length(bp) + i)])
test = test | is.na(test)
res = which(apply(test, 1, all))
res = lapply(res, function(x) x + seq_along(bp) - 1)
final = lapply(res, function(z) x[z])
names(final) = lapply(res, "[", 1)

# $`11`
# [1] "creme" "sugar" "sugar" "milk"  "milk" 
# 
# $`12`
# [1] "sugar" "sugar" "milk"  "milk"  "creme"
# 
# $`56`
# [1] "milk"  "sugar" "carw"  "milk"  "carw" 
# 
# $`73`
# [1] "creme" "sugar" "milk"  "milk"  "carw" 
# 
# $`80`
# [1] "creme" "sugar" "carw"  "milk"  "sugar"
# 
# $`83`
# [1] "milk"  "sugar" "sugar" "milk"  "sugar"
# 
# $`86`
# [1] "milk"  "sugar" "creme" "milk"  "milk" 
# 
# $`108`
# [1] "carw"  "sugar" "milk"  "milk"  "milk"
```

The result is a named list where the name is the starting index of `x` and the value is the matched vector. This gives you both the "where" as well as the match in one object.